# Multitasking in iOS4 : sending push data from background process

Tags: ios4, multitasking

In OS4 the idea is sold to client is that the app is opened in background, and even if the user is on another app, the app can push data to server on regular basis (which would trigger push notifications btw)
BUT on what i read on the internet is that IOS4 multitasking is a fake one :
- it freezes the app, and doesn't leave it in background
- the developper has to specify the app must work in IOS4 (iOS4 qualification process) to ensure that returning on the app won't start agin from beginning

So can anyone confirm that in iOS4 on iphone 4 the app can push data to server in background process ?

Answer (score 0):

Apps can receive and respond to location events in the background in two ways:

1. Applications can register for significant location changes only (your app runs in the background when a significant change in location occurs).
2. An application can declare itself as a continuous background location application (full-time background processing in response to all location events).

There's more information about iOS 4 multitasking available in Apple's guide to [What's new in iOS 4](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html), and the [iOS 4 Application Programming Guide's Background Tasks section](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW2).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
In this doc it says "An application can declare itself as supporting specific services that require regular background execution time."
I'm interested in sending GPS coordinates to server, via a http call, would that be possible ?
What are these specific services that require regular background execution time ?

Comment: @peekpoke Go read Apple's iOS Application Programming Guide, specifically the section on [receiving locaton events in the background](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW2)